# How to count items in multidimensional array, separating them by "type"?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have items, that i'm getting from db in multidimensional array like this one(only part of array), how to count them separated by key "type" with php code, problem is - that can be more than one item key "count" (like first part of array)? I can count them by "type" key, cos different item have different type, but don't know how to count multiple of them. Example: i can get result : Counted type 0 = 2, type 2 = 1 with counting keys by "type" but don't know how to get correct count :  **Counted type 0 = 5, type 2 = 2** cos i have not 1 item in "count" key.

```
                Array
(
    [id] => 212
    [type] => 0
    [number] => 342
    [price] => 10
    [count] => 1
    [price_count] => (€10-1pcs)
)
Array
(
    [id] => 213
    [type] => 0
    [number] => 343
    [price] => 10
    [count] => 4
    [price_count] => (€10-4pcs)
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1014
    [type] => 2
    [number] => 344
    [price] => 10
    [count] => 2
    [price_count] => (€10-2pcs)
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not write some code that loops over that array and counts?

Comment: trying code from answers

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   if (!isset($count[$value['type']])) {
        $count[$value['type']] = 0;
   }
    
    $count[$value['type']] += $value['count'];
}

print_r($count);
```

Comment: counting only count of keys by type, ignoring count key. i need to get item count, 1 and 2 item in array is same item(type = 0), 3 is another one item(type = 2). I need to get item count : type 0 item count = 5 , type 2 item count = 2, cos in count is item count. here is my problem, i don't know how to include in counting second key "count"

Comment: You need Type = count of this type ?

Comment: I need :  Type 0 (count keys Type 0 * count if count > 1) , Type 2 (count keys Type 2 * count if count > 1)
in common : this array - show items in db, item type 0 is 5 pcs. item type 2 is 2pcs , can't get this done, only getting item type 0 is 2(cos two keys with type 0) and item type 2 is 1(cos one key with type 2), how to count similar (same type items) first and second is type 0 - same item

Comment: @Amimistik update answer

Comment: getting Array ( [0] => 7 ), is it possible to separate them? to get type 0 = 5, type 2 = 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a second array and foreach the first like:

```
$array = [
    [
    'id' => 212,
    'type' => 0,
    'number' => 342,
    'price' => 10,
    'count' => 1,
    'price_count' => '(€10-1pcs)'
]
,[
    'id' => 213,
    'type' => 0,
    'number' => 343,
    'price' => 10,
    'count' => 4,
    'price_count' => '(€10-4pcs)'
]
,[
    'id' => 1014,
    'type' => 2,
    'number' => 344,
    'price' => 10,
    'count' => 2,
    'price_count' => '(€10-2pcs)'
]];

$newArr = ['type' => [], 'count' => []];
foreach($array as $secondArray){
    foreach($secondArray as $key => $value){
        if($key === 'type'){
            if(in_array($value, $newArr['type'])){
                $newArr['type'][$value]++;
            }else{
                $newArr['type'][$value] = 1;  
            }
        }
        if($key === 'count'){
            if(in_array($value, $newArr['count'])){
                $newArr['count'][$value]++;
            }else{
                $newArr['count'][$value] = 1;  
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

This code will output:

```
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [count] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [4] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

You can extend my code hardcoded others fields or you can create all dynamically

Comment: strange, if i use array from your code, getting same input like you, if using my array - getting:

    Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
        )

    [count] => Array
        (
        )

)
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
        )

    [count] => Array
        (
        )

)
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
        )

    [count] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: I can see only what you wrote in your question :) So update with right array

Comment: Array ( [type] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [count] => Array ( [1] => 1 [4] => 1 [2] => 1 ) ), sorry my fault, was putting code in wrong place.

Comment: So it's correct :)?

Comment: yep code is correct, but not solving my problem, i need to get result like Type 0 count = 5 , type 2 count = 2, cos type mean item type, i need to count common count separated by type.

Comment: How my code work it's exctaly what you wrote, indeed if you see my output  Type 0 => 1, you can foreach it and use as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get count of type `0` or `1`

`echo array_count_values(array_column($array, 'type'))[0]; // outputs: 2`

where

`$array` is your array

`'type'` is the key name

`[0]` is your key value that you want to count

Comment: simple not showing at all

Comment: counting only keys "type", i need to cound depending on Type and count keys, to get result Type 0 = 5, type 2 = 2

Comment: $type0 =  array_count_values(array_column($array, 'type'))[0]; // outputs: 2

Comment: $type2 =  array_count_values(array_column($array, 'type'))[2]; // outputs: 1

Comment: Besides, your question is not very clear, what response do you need?